# add positive and negative floating point values in c

Tags: c, floating-point

I know, *another* topic on floating point arithmetic!

I've been trying to wrap my head around this and can't seem to come up with why adding negative floating point values isn't working for me.

If they're both positive values everything is working as expected (returns numbers that aren't wildly out of what was expected, since this is floating point after all).

I'm using the 32bit version, incase it wasn't obvious ;)

I've already read through this: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html 
And have found various, and great, explanations of floating point arithmetic online – however, I still can't seem to figure out how to add mixed positive and negative values (or case 2, 3, and 4 in the code below).

Here's my code thus far:

```
int flt32_get_sign (flt32 x) {

    /** shift sign bit right; 0 = pos, 1 = neg */
    return ((x & 0x80000000) >> 31);
}

int flt32_get_exp (flt32 x) {

    /** get biaseed exponent value */
    return ((x & 0x7F800000) >> 23);
}

int flt32_get_val (flt32 x) {

    /** mask off mantissa 
    *   make sure implicit one set 
    */
    return ((x & 0x7FFFFF) ^ 0x800000);
}

int flt32_left_most_1 (int bits) {

    int position = -1;

    /** make sure working with abs value */
    if (flt32_get_sign(bits) != 0){
        bits = flt32_negate(bits);
    }

    while(bits != 0){
        position++, bits >>=1;
    }

    return position;
}

int flt32_right_most_1 (int bits) {

    int position = -1;

    /** make sure working with abs value */
    if (flt32_get_sign(bits) != 0){
        bits = flt32_negate(bits);
    }

    while (!(bits & 1)){
       position++, bits >>=1;
    }

    return position;
}

flt32 flt32_abs (flt32 x) {

    return (x & 0x7FFFFFFF);
}

flt32 flt32_negate (flt32 x) {

    if (flt32_get_sign(x) == 0){
        /** is possitive */
        return (x ^ 0x80000000);
    }
    /** else is negative */
    return (x & 0x7FFFFFFF);
}

flt32 flt32_add (flt32 x, flt32 y) {

    /** 
    *   Possible casses:
    *   1: +x +y; 2: +x -y; 3: -x +y; 4: -x -y
    */

    flt32 sum, x_val, y_val;
    int shift;


    /** Case 1 */
    if (flt32_get_sign(x) == 0 && flt32_get_sign(y) == 0){
        if (flt32_get_exp(x) == flt32_get_exp(y)){
            /** no shifting neccesary 
            *   add mantissa's then mask to make sure
            *   we don't get overflow into the exponent bits
            *   then add exponent back to new value
            */
            sum = (x & 0x7F800000) + ((flt32_get_val(x) + flt32_get_val(y)) & 0x7FFFFF);

        } else if (flt32_get_exp(x) > flt32_get_exp(y)){
            /** exponent of x is larger than y
            *   need to right shift y and set its exponent = exponent of x
            */
            shift = (flt32_get_exp(x) - flt32_get_exp(y));
            y_val = flt32_get_exp(x) + (flt32_get_val(y) >> shift);

            sum = x + y_val;

        } else {
            /** exponent x is smaller than y
            *   need to right shift x and set its exponent = exponent of y 
            */
            shift = (flt32_get_exp(y) - flt32_get_exp(x));
            x_val = flt32_get_exp(y) + (flt32_get_val(x) >> shift);

            sum = x_val + y;
        }
    }

    /** Case 2 */
    if (flt32_get_sign(x) == 0 && flt32_get_sign(y) == 1){
        if (flt32_get_exp(x) == flt32_get_exp(y)){
            /** no shifting neccesary 
            *   add mantissa's then mask to make sure
            *   we don't get overflow into the exponent bits
            *   then add exponent back to new value
            */
            x_val = ((x & 0xFF800000) + flt32_get_val(x));
            y_val = ((y & 0xFF800000) + flt32_get_val(y));

            sum = x_val + flt32_negate(y_val);

        } else if (flt32_get_exp(x) > flt32_get_exp(y)){
            /** exponent of x is larger than y
            *   need to right shift y and set its exponent = exponent of x
            */
            shift = (flt32_get_exp(x) - flt32_get_exp(y));
            y_val = flt32_get_exp(x) + (flt32_get_val(y) >> shift);

            sum = x + flt32_negate(y_val);

        } else {
            /** exponent x is smaller than y
            *   need to right shift x and set its exponent = exponent of y 
            */
            shift = (flt32_get_exp(y) - flt32_get_exp(x));
            x_val = flt32_get_exp(y) + (flt32_get_val(x) >> shift);

            sum = x_val + flt32_negate(y);
        }
    }

    return sum;
}
```

*Aside*: just an observation that I made while wrapping my head around all of this; it seems that it's great, and even necessary, to understand floating points – but almost every article I've come across, even text books, say to avoid it when possible! :)

Comment: You can live a fulfilling programmer life without ever having to write floating-point operations yourself, if you ask me.

Comment: `>> shift` is only good for a small range like 0 to 31 or 63 and your `shift` has values potentially greater.

Comment: Looks like you have `|` and `^` mixed up. `|` will effectively set the bit, `^` does and exclusive or (XOR).

Comment: flt32_get_val() is wrong.  Setting the hidden bit should be conditional if exponent > 0.  Recommend using `^` and not `|` here.

Comment: It is important to understand how floating point behaves, in order to evaluate whether you should or should not be using it in a given situation. The classic document for this is [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html). However, writing a software floating point implementation is more a matter of bit twiddling than understanding.

Comment: @Patricia Shanahan – congratulations, you win! ...for being the first responder to link to this without reading my post :) look at the link I posted above, I've already read this document (and mention that) in it's entirety. And snippets of it multiple times. Still did not help me fully understand hence the reason for this posting ;)

Comment: @Freddie – thanks! Didn't realize that, still new to C and trying to figure out all the operators.

Comment: @zneak – thank god! Almost every single post and document I came across for floating point is homework/lecture related.

Answer (score 2):

Case 2 considerations

After  `sum = x + flt32_negate(y_val)`, should `sum <  0x800000`, you need to normalize answer:  Left shift until not so, decrementing exponent as you go.  Watch for `sum == 0` first and return specially formed 0.  You will not check for underflow when decrementing bias exponent once you fix `flt32_get_val()`.

Further difference issue:  Subtraction (+ case 2) must be done such that any bits shifted out as part of `shift` are brought back in due to the `sum <  0x800000` issue.  If any bit remains shifted out, rounding must be assessed and handled.

Consider handing + and - though common routines and vectoring off to adding/subtracting magnitudes.  + cases 1,2,3,4 are  like - case 1,4,3,2.  + case 1,4 are the same, just different sign.  + case 2,3 are negations of each other once you find which is greater in magnitude first.

Consider handling +0, -0 as special cases at first.

You are doing nothing about INF and NAN.  Recommend to save for later, put in stubs for now.

---

Case 1 considerations

If `sum > 0xFFFFFF`, you need to right sift and increment exponent, test for exponent overflow and the returning INF.

If you right shift, OP needs to decide on rounding mode and potentially increment answer, again testing for increment exponent, test for exponent overflow and the returning INF.

---

After making `sum`, answer reconstitution must be careful to deal with hidden MSBit.

OP is mixing up use of | vs. ^.

OP has a long way to go, I'd estimate OP is 10% done with the add case.

Comment: `flt32_get_exp (flt32 x)` needs special handling when the raw bits are 0.

Comment: thank you for the advice, understand the code has a ways to go. And I know I still need to handle the NaN and INF issues as well. My issue was figuring out what needs to come first. I thought I could figure out the algorithm for addition first and from there I could figure out how to handle the extreme cases.

Comment: @shparkison  Its a daunting task.  I admire your tenacity.  BTW: consider typedef'ing your integer type and FP type and #define'ing magic numbers like `0xFF800000` so you may easily adapt your routines to `double` & `long double`.